# Perform `jmp segment:offset` where `segment` is not an immediate value

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have a jump like so:

```
jmp 0x8:label
```

I would like to replace the `0x8` constant with a value from for example the `eax` register:

```
jmp eax:label
```

Unfortunately NASM does not allow this. What alternative do I have to achieve this?

Comment: NASM doesn't support it because the processor doesn't support it. One method is to push the segment on the stack (eax), push the offset on the stack (label) and then do a far return. Doing a far return would act as a jump but this method allows a runtime value for the segment.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ah, very clever - I think that method will work for my use case. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You could also push the values as mentioned in my first comment and do an indirect  far jump using ESP as the address containing the address to jump to. I have an example of that in this answer (although it is in AT&T syntax). It could be converted to NASM. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49439075/3857942

Comment: You either need both values immediate, or both values in memory.